# PHP Json will not save full array

Tags: php, arrays, json, string

```
    if(isset($_POST['button'])) {

        $myfile = fopen("test.txt", "w") or die("Cannot open!");
        $txt = '';
        foreach($result_set as $result) {
            $asd = $txt.json_encode($result['firstname']);
            echo $asd;
        }

        fwrite($myfile, $asd);
        fclose($myfile);
}
```

I got this json but it only saves one firstname in the .txt instead of all names, but if I echo

> $asd

it shows me all names.

How do I solve this?

EDIT: (result_set)

```
// DB
$db = DBWrapper::getInstance();  
#Selecting data
$table = "staff";
$columns = array("id", "firstname");
$whereDish  = array('categorie_bit = :idDish');
$valuesDish = array('idDish' => 10);

#random select
$whereRand  = array('categorie_bit = :idRand');

$orderbyrandom = array('RAND()');
$result_set = $db->select($table, "*", $whereDish, $valuesDish, $orderbyrandom, 10);
```

Comment: what is `$result_set` ? where it come from ?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are writing again and again to $asd.

Try this.initialize `$asd = ''`

And in the foreach append to $asd

```
$asd .= $txt.json_encode($result['firstname']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply something like:

```
<?php
    if( isset( $_POST['button'] ) ) {
        $txt = '';
        foreach( $result_set as $result ) {
            file_put_contents( 'test.txt', $txt . json_encode( $result['firstname'] ), FILE_TEXT | FILE_APPEND );
        }
    }
?>
```

Or, as perhaps I think you intend ( because json_encode on a single name will probably not yield anything useful - just a series of names within quotes rather than a json object )

```
<?php
    if( isset( $_POST['button'] ) ) {
        $tmp=array();
        $txt = '';

        foreach( $result_set as $result ) {
            $tmp[]=$txt . $result['firstname'];
        }
        file_put_contents( 'test.txt', json_encode( $tmp ), FILE_TEXT | FILE_APPEND );
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:

```
<?php
    if( isset( $_POST['button'] ) ) {

        private $txt;
         $txt = "\n";
        foreach( $result_set as $result ) {
            file_put_contents( 'test.txt', $txt . json_encode( $result['firstname'] ), a );
        }
    }
?>
```